# WSO2 Enterprise Integrator DSS

Tags: postgresql, wso2, enterprise, wso2-data-services-server, integrator

I would like to ask a question about the dss.
I'm creating queries to expose services rest by retrieving data from a db postrgresql.
I would like to expose a service that, based on an incoming parameter (table name), retrieves all of that table. But I have a problem.
I do not know a priori the number and the name of the columns in this table. So I wonder how I can map the output (maybe in a generic object)? It's possible to do it? Or do I need to know the name of the columns absolutely?

Thanks a lot

Comment: I believe you need to know schema upfront. I'd consider such a service very bad (and insecure) practice

Comment: You can use some combination of dynamic SQL and stored procedure on DB side, if postgresql allows that. But I agree, that is a bad practice

Answer (score 0):

The DSS requires you to define what the response will look like beforehand. It is not dynamic like that.